# Session state are different for same domain with/without www prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, azure, session-cookies

I have Azure(C#/MVC) project which uses session state. I store sessions in Cache shared in memory of my role instances. But session state stored in http://mydomain.com and http://www.mydomain.com are different. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you compare the session-id in the cookie on both domains?

Comment: yes, they are different

Comment: Then @Alexander Galkin answer addresses that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your question is not tagged, I assume that you are using IIS for hosting your MVC project on Azure and you are using cookies for session management.

In this case you need to consolidate the domains into one in your `web.config`:

```
<httpCookies domain="mydomain.com"/>
```

Now both the subdomain and the main domain should have same session IDs.

Comment: I've added this line /configuration/system.web/ but issue still stays on :/

Comment: @Daive: You still have two different cookies? Do both the subdomain and the main domain map to the same ASP.NET Application? Did you restart the IIS after the change? Unfortunately I can't now test it, but try removing the dot in the domain attribute and retry.

Comment: @Daive: I edited my answer accordingly. Please, do not hesitate to tag the answer as correct if it worked for you, so that others would benefit from it as well :)